# Can I add css style to this &#8226;?

Tags: html, css

Can I write some style css code for every `&#8226;` code I use in my page, for example `font-size: 16px;`? Thanks.

Comment: Btw: the "normal" HTML entity is named `&bull;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have answered the main question; you cannot specify a CSS Rule based on text content (just on HTML elements, classes, and ids).

What you *could* do is use Javascript, or server-side rendering to do a `.Replace()` to wrap the character with the necessary HTML tags (replace just the character with a wrapped version of the character).

---

[Here's a quick proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/55Ruh/); it could easily avoid the jQuery (it's a crutch of mine), and you might play around a bit with how the character is encoded in the Javascript (I had to copy/paste it in to work).

The key portion is:

```
.replace("•","<span class='bullet'>•</span>")
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot. You cannot style text content, no matter how it’s encoded (either as direct characters or as entities).

The closest thing you can do is put `<span class="bullet">•</span>` into the document and style the class `bullet`.

Answer (score 0):

No. With CSS you can only address elements but not certain characters (ok, there are exceptions like `:first-letter`). You would need to put it into an element like `span`:

```
<span class="bullet">&#8226;</span>
```

Then you can use the selector `span.bullet` to style these elements:

```
span.bullet {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```